# Difference between if (x) { foo(); } and x ? foo() : 0;

Tags: javascript

Snippet 1:

```
if ( x ) { 
    foo();
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
x ? foo() : 0;
```

What are the differences between those two snippets?

**Edit:** Corrected the syntax error.

**Update**: btw, it seems that there is an even shorter notation:

```
x && foo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `if` is a statement (e.g. you can't assign it to a variable) and the ternary operator `?:` is part of an expression (yields a value which can be assigned to variables).

Also, the `if` block can contain statements while the components of `?:` can only contain expressions.

In the example you give, there is no difference, since you don't use the result of the `?:`.
Both snippets evaluate `foo()` only if x is a true value.

Answer (score 8):

Snippet #2 is an invalid ECMAScript expression since it lacks the required `: blah` in order to make it a ternary.

**EDIT:** There isn't really a difference between the two snippets, they both invoke `foo` if `x` is truthy. If `x` is falsy (undefined/false/empty string/0/) then first snippet wouldn't evaluate to anything, latter snippet would evaluate to `0` but that `0` really has no impact on the script.

Comment: Also, the block syntax does not evaluate to any value (it's not an expression).  The ternary operator does evaluate to a value.

Comment: @cdhowie Yea, but the ternary expression is not assigned to anything in my code, so this is not a difference in this case.

Comment: If we had `x ? foo() : bar()` and the functions didn't return anything. Would it be ECMA valid because it's actually value `undefined`?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. Expressions can be used as statements. And any function can return `undefined` without error. It's when you try to *use* the value `undefined` that you crash.

Comment: @meder OK, I figured it out. Thanks. (I thought there might be a slight distinction between those two, but I guess there isn't.)

Comment: Ok do it works as expected, but do I interpret the answer as "yes that is good ECMA script"?

Comment: @Martin It's a shortcut notation. As long as your right-hand sides are just expressions, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to ask the following

```
// Why should I use
if (x) {
  do();
}

// instead of 
x && do();
```

or

```
// Why should I use
if (x) {
  do(); 
} else {
  dont();
}

//instead of 
x ? do() : dont()
```

As they are written, there is no difference in the output. I don't like using the ternary or the && operator in these cases because of the semantics of using the ternary and &&. A ternary returns a value that you're not using, as does the && expression. Therefore, I'd rather use the way the language intends operators to be used.

However, I love using && for null checks

```
var val = obj && obj.getValue();
```

Note that in this case, we are using the return value of the expression

Comment: +1 I like this technique: `x && foo();` instead of `if (x) { foo(); }`. I'll remember that. :)

Comment: Sure... even though that was my anti-suggestion. I used to use it, but was convinced by fellow developers not to do it.