# A different syntax for if statements

Tags: javascript

Does it make sense to sometimes replace `if` statements by `&&` statements? By this I mean replace

```
if(a) {
    b();
}
```

by

```
a && b();
```

Are these forms equivalent? Is the terser style recommended in some situations?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970346/what-is-x-foo

Comment: Just to add more to what others have said, they will behave equivalently, except that 1) jslint and similar tools may complain about the second. 2) the second returns a value, not that you're capturing it.

Comment: @thomasrutter As Doug said jslint with hurt your feelings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the forms are more or less equivalent. However, there is one subtle difference:

If statements are just statements. They do not return or express a value.

The logical AND operator forms an expression. It returns or **expresses** a value.

It generally not a good idea to use an expression in place of a statement. It could lead to unexpected results. For example, when used in a bookmarklet if the expression is not voided then the document is replaced by the expression.

As a general rule always use the if statement for code branching, use the conditional operator to express one of two different expressions, and use the logical AND and OR operators as **guard** and **default** expressions respectively.

The concept of statements and expressions are fundamental to all languages. Even natural languages (compare with sentences and phrases). We use both of them for a reason. It's generally not a good idea to mix them up. Besides, they serve as a form of documentatiom for other programmers and are easier to read and debug.

Hope this post doesn't fall on oblivious ears. =)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are equivalent. Of course the `if` is much more readable.

The `&&` is the logical AND operator, for efficient evaluation, it can short cut: if the left hand part of the statement returns a falsy value, the second part is not evaluated and the whole expression will return `false`.

If the left hand part of the statement instead has a truthy value, the second part is evaluated in order to determine the result.

With your expression `a && b();`, you're using a side effect of this operator (the short cut mechanism), you're not using the logical AND operation result. While it works, I would not recommend it.