# How can I use setInterval or setTimeout and display the results during the count?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a timer count down from 5 seconds to zero before a function is called, and I can do that successfully, but I haven't yet been able to display the timer value as it counts down. Instead of displaying the values, the `<div></div>` goes from a blank space to "Number: 0".  I've used both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` with the same result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        function countDown() {
            setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "Number: " + i;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

*I also tried using `.value` in place of `.innerHTML` with no help.*

```
<input type="button" value="Count" onclick="countDown()" />

<div id="displayDiv" />
```

This seems like it should be really simple, but it has me stumped.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your attempt is failing because you aren't calling the function, you are just executing the code to create a named function expression 5 times and never calling it.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function countDown(i) {
    var int = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "Number: " + i;
        i-- || clearInterval(int);  //if i is 0, then stop the interval
    }, 1000);
}
countDown(5);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/sFtqZ/ (extra callback argument included)

Comment: @RobG - Seems better, changed.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It looks cleaner and thanks for the reference too!

Comment: Thanks. If you think my answer did helped you out, you can pressed that green checkmark to accept this answer. ;)

Comment: I've gone over a part of your code that doesn't make sense to me.  How does... "`i-- || clearInterval(int);`" work?  I get (or assume) that it's an `OR`, but how does it know to stop at zero?  Why not stop at 3 or -15?  Where's the `if` or it's equivalent?  It looks like clearInterval(int) could be valid at any time so I don't understand that either.  Could you have more options there like `i-- || (x==0) || clearInterval(int);`?

Comment: @JonDoeCA - It is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). `a || b()` simply means `if a is false, then do b()`. In `i-- || clearInterval(int)`, when `i--` is `0 (0 is false)`, then do `clearInterval(int)`. Best use for lazy people like me!

Comment: That's very cool! My mind is a bit numb from analyzing it, there's a lot going on in that little statement.  Thanks so much for that!

Comment: (I asked this question 1 year ago on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970346/what-is-x-foo `;)`)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown() {
var i = 5;
var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "Number: " + i;

    if (i === 0) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        //call your function
    }
    else {
        i--;
       }
    }, 1000);
}​
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjSKa/