# Resting Countdown function when it reach 60 second

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a counter function I got it from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075960) :

```
  function countDown(i) {
    var int = setInterval(function () {
        document.querySelector(".count").innerHTML = "Number: " + i;
        i-- || clearInterval(int);  //if i is 0, then stop the interval
    }, 1000);
}
countDown(60);
```

So when it finishes counting it stops at 0;

What I'm trying to achieve when the counter stops at zero I want to reset the function to count down from 60 to 0.

Is it possible to reset the function?
I'm really lost at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achive this is to not stop the counter at all. Just set the value of `i` to 60 when it's value is 0.

```
function countDown(i) {
    var int = setInterval(function () {
        document.querySelector(".count").innerHTML = "Number: " + i;
        i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : 60;
    }, 1000);
}
countDown(60);
```

Comment: a simple and easy solution, Brilliant!

Comment: This is a great solution, but I have two suggestions. 1- avoid using `int` as a variable. It's a [reserved keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). 2- move the document selector outside the interval for efficiency. Other wise you keep scanning the dom each time.