# Trying to shorten a conditional statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to do here is use the fewest bytes to call function `f` only if the variable `a` is not null. The function `n` shown will work fine, but according to my web browser, function `m` won't work. The browser states:

> expected expression, got ';'

I then proceeded to take out the colon, figuring maybe that would do the trick, but I get the error "syntax error".

Is there a way I can shorten function n to a smaller size and have it still work or should I just stick with function `n`?

```
function g(){}
function f(){}

function m(){a?f()g():;}

function n(){if(a){f();g()}}
```

Comment: Why excactly do you care for smaller size?

Comment: m will not work since f()g() is not valid...browser tells you why

Comment: My browser reports a syntax error at hte `g`, it doesn't even reach the one after the `:`.

Comment: What is the practical reason for that? Code must be readable, size is what minifiers + gzip were invented for?

Comment: I'm trying to compact my code because I have a lot of javascript and I want to make guests download fewer bytes.

Comment: Are you trying to minify, by hand? There are a number of tools to do this more efficiently, and more quickly, for free...

Comment: @Mike Do you realize their are resources that already do this for you? Did you try and see if it shrink it down for you?

Comment: @Mike: No reason to do that by hand. There's a variety of tools that has automated this.

Comment: If I rely on 3rd party tools to do all my code shrinking, then I'll be doing things their way and I'll be learning nothing. Additionally, their results might not work for older browsers.

Comment: And the answer you selected is not the shortest....

Comment: @Vohuman what if they are about to apply for a junior JS-minifier position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some tricks with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
function m(){a?(f(),g()):…}
```

and of course the conditional operator always needs a third operand, you cannot just omit it, but use any (short) value:

```
function m(){a?(f(),g()):0}
```

You can work around that restriction by using the short-circuit behaviour of the AND operator (see [What is "x && foo()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572)):

```
function m(){a&&(f(),g())}
```

But **don't do that**. It makes your code totally unreadable.

> Should I just stick with function n?

Yes, definitely.

```
function m() {
    if (a) {
        f();
        g();
    }
}
```

If you want to minify that, use [one of the established minifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1737388/1048572) instead of hand-optimising it.

Comment: " It makes your code totally unreadable." It is supposed to be when you are manually compacting it.

Answer (score 3):

Code golfing?

*Fore!*

*ahem*

You could use `&&` for the conditional, and `+` to call them both together.

```
function m(){a&&f()+g()}
```

## Total bytes: 24

Note: If by chance `f` or `g` returns an object, any `valueOf` methods will be called, which could have side-effects, but in this context I think that's unlikely.

Comment: beats closure compiler by 2

Comment: If `f` or `g` return an object that implements a `valueOf` that has side effects then it would behave differently to `if (a) { f(); g(); }`

Comment: @zerkms True, but in this context I'm doubtful they return anything. I'll make a note of it though.

Comment: I'm gonna try every answer and see what works for IE 7 too.