# What is ...!! syntax in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading through this: https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/blob/master/src/index.js

I know that `...` is being used as Object spread. I know that `!!` is used to convert anything into a boolean with the same truthiness.

However knowing this what do they mean when they're put together like `...!!`? I have trouble understanding the last line here:

```
{
  ...resolveAction,
  ...isAction(rejected) ? rejected : {
    ...!!rejected && { payload: rejected }
}
```

1. `...resolveAction` just spreads the keys of `resolveAction`.
2. `...isAction(rejected) ?` will check if `rejected` resolves an action and then will spread it. (Not sure about this one either)
3. add `rejected` to object if true
4. `{...!!rejected && { payload: rejected }` ????????????????

How is `...!!` even valid syntax? There are two options:

1. If it spreads the object first, then `!!` would be applied to all the spread keys
2. If `!!` is applied first it's a boolean value and it can't be spread.

So does it make no sense whatsoever, or am I missing something because given that code, I assume it's trying to spread a boolean value.

Comment: In that repo, `rejected` is an object (line 54).  Maybe the spread operator in conjunction with `!!` inverts each property of the object?

Comment: My guess is, and this is only a guess since I haven't found anything in the ES6 spec about precendences, that `...` has a low precedence so actually the spread is applied to `rejected && { payload: rejected }`. So what the code is actually testing is that there is a rejected value and if so pass it as a key called `payload`

Comment: @nbermudezs I think you're on to something. An `&&` will return the second value if the first is truthy, so the object gets spread into the parent object.

Comment: @nbermudezs If that's the case, I'd argue the maintainers of redux should add some brackets to make this more clear, and not end up with [questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator).

Comment: @ScottKaye lol, yeah, although it is arguable that the maintainers will like to stick with a code style exploiting the most out of the language therefore knowing deeply the language is a must

Comment: @ScottKaye this isn't made by the creator, but rather is made by community member. However, I agree that it's pretty bad, and I've since written my own version.

Comment: Using `!!` to force a value to be treated as a boolean is an idiomatic thing in JavaScript. I'm not sure I see the problem here.

Comment: Ok right, that makes sense :)

Comment: That seems to be missing a closing brace, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after downloading the npm module and going through the transpiled code I found the line:

```
return dispatch(isThunk(rejected) ? rejected.bind(null, resolveAction) : _extends({}, resolveAction, isAction(rejected) ? rejected : _extends({}, !!rejected && { payload: rejected })));
```

Of which the relevant part is here:

```
_extends({}, !!rejected && { payload: rejected })
```

Basically if `!!rejected` is true then it'll spread the payload into the object. If it's not `_extends({}, false)` just returns `{}`.

The key to this working is that `...` has less precedence than any other operator in the entire line. With that in mind you can begin to make sense of it.

Comment: You don't even need to d/l the trainspiled code.  Just use babel repl on their site.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant question is [What is "x && foo()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572)

The weird syntax

```
{...!!rejected && { payload: rejected }}
```

is parsed as

```
{ ... ((!!rejected) && { payload: rejected }) }
```

Indeed the `!!` does cast `rejected` to a boolean, then it is evaluated to the object when truthy. A better way to write this would be

```
{ ...(rejected ? {payload: rejected} : null) }
```

---

And of course the whole inner object literal is superfluous. It could just be

```
{
  ...resolveAction,
  ...(isAction(rejected) ? rejected : (rejected ? {payload: rejected} : null))
}
```

(omit parentheses as you see fit)

Comment: At the time that I asked this, I genuinely thought ...!! was some kind of unique operator. I knew what && meant, but didn't know how low the precedence of ... was which was the key to figuring it out. So while this answer is right, it misses the mark on what I was actually asking which would be "in what order is (...) (!!) and (&&) evaluated"

Comment: @AR7: I think the "is parsed as" paragraph explains precedence/evaluation order, doesn't it?

Comment: yeah I agreed with you there and said "the answer is right."  The only part I have issue with is he first sentence. I know what 'x && foo()' means. The caveat here is that it was '...!!x && foo()', which confused me.