# How to output a specific object in Node.js but don't output those that do not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

like so

````
► add language identifier to highlight code
fdfsd
```python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
````

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links (use https whenever possible)
https://example.com
[example](https://example.com)
[example](https://example.com)

Comment: You use a guard, e.g. `var grade = obj[i].Statistics && obj[i].Statistics[i] && obj[i].Statistics[i].Grade;`. There has to be a good dupetarget to point this at, I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970346/what-is-x-foo

Comment: Beside that error, there are other problems like returning from the loop and using `i` as the index for the inner array.

Comment: I tried putting the output code outside the loop but it doesn't seem to fix it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for existence of `Statistics` first before accessing it,

change this

```
 var grade = obj[i].Statistics[i].Grade;
 var hasPassOrFail = obj[i].Statistics[i].Status;
```

to this

```
  var grade = obj[i] && obj[i].Statistics && obj[i].Statistics[0] && obj[i].Statistics[0].Grade;
  var hasPassOrFail = obj[i] && obj[i].Statistics && obj[i].Statistics[0] && obj[i].Statistics[0].Status;
```

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"Name":"Student1","Id":44844541,"Statistics":[{"Grade":6,"Status":"Pass"}]},{"Name":"Student2","Id":48484848},{"Name":"Student3","Id":99999989,"Statistics":[{"Grade":2,"Status":"Fail"}]}]')

for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {

  var grade = obj[i] && obj[i].Statistics && obj[i].Statistics[0] && obj[i].Statistics[0].Grade;
  var hasPassOrFail = obj[i] && obj[i].Statistics && obj[i].Statistics[0] && obj[i].Statistics[0].Status;

  if (grade || hasPassOrFail){
   console.log(grade,hasPassOrFail)
  }
}
```